# Three quotation marks instead of one

Tags: python, csv

I want transfer/write a list of lists into a txt file. Some of the strings in the lists contain quotation  marks, which should be transferred, too.

But if I try to write them in the txt file they contain three quotation marks before and three after the string. How can I change `"""3"""` to `"3"` and `"""A1"""` to `"A1"` in the txt without doing it by hand? (the list of lists contains 65.000 lists...) The numbers without quotation marks should stay like they are.

```
import csv

results = ['"3"', '"300.096"', '"0.033"', '45.4715', '35.903', '1', '0.205328', '0.0702029201671833', '"0"', '"A1"', '"STAR-"'],['"3"', '"300.096"', '"0.033"', '45.4715', '35.903', '1', '0.205328', '0.0702029201671833', '"0"', '"A1"', '"STAR-"']

path = "C:\\Users\\kaza\\Desktop\\Bla.txt"
with open(path, "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerows(A)
```

the result I get looks like this

```
"""3""","""300.096""","""0.033""",45.4715,35.903,1,0.205328,0.0702029201671833,"""0""","""A1""","""STAR-"""
"""3""","""300.096""","""0.033""",45.4715,35.903,1,0.205328,0.0702029201671833,"""0""","""A1""","""STAR-"""`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are writing data *with* quotes. The `csv.writer()` by default uses quote characters already, to surround data that may have the delimiter in the value, and will escape any `"` characters *in the value* with double `""` marks before surrounding the value with `".."` quotes of their own.

Either don't include the quotes in the value (and leave quoting to the `csv.writer()` class) or disable quote escaping.

Disabling quote escaping can be done by setting [`quoting`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.quoting) to [`csv.QUOTE_NONE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_NONE) and setting the [`quotechar`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.quotechar) value to `None`:

```
writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n', 
                    quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar=None)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import csv
>>> output = BytesIO()
>>> writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar=None)
>>> results = ['"3"', '"300.096"', '"0.033"', '45.4715', '35.903', '1', '0.205328', '0.0702029201671833', '"0"', '"A1"', '"STAR-"'],['"3"', '"300.096"', '"0.033"', '45.4715', '35.903', '1', '0.205328', '0.0702029201671833', '"0"', '"A1"', '"STAR-"']
>>> writer.writerow(results[0])
84L
>>> writer.writerow(results[1])
84L
>>> print(output.getvalue())
"3","300.096","0.033",45.4715,35.903,1,0.205328,0.0702029201671833,"0","A1","STAR-"
"3","300.096","0.033",45.4715,35.903,1,0.205328,0.0702029201671833,"0","A1","STAR-"
```

When you do set `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE`, you probably want to specify a value for [`escapechar`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.escapechar), so that any appearances of the delimiter or the line terminator in a value can be handled properly.